# JQ: Set toplevel path

Tags: json, jq

I use jq 1.5 under a Windows enviroment to modify a given large json file to extract a single Array ("Offers") from that large file:

```
'.Offers[] | ({Price: .AdultPriceEUR, Currency: .Currency, Link: .Deeplink, Tickettyp: .TicketClassIndex, Flightindex: .FlightIndex })'
```

After that i got an "unnamed" Array. But for the later processing it is necessary that the Array keeps his old "Name". I checked the documentation and found the setpath function but it is not possible to keep the Name "easy" on extraction?

shorten example of the json file:

```
   {"Airports": [
    {
        "Aliases": null,
        "ContinentCode": "EU",
        "ContinentGroup": 1,
        "CountryCode": "DE",
        "CountryName": "Germany",
        "DST": "",
        "DisplayName": "Hamburg (HAM) Germany",
        "Iata": "HAM",
        "IataLink": false,
        "Icao": "EDDH",
        "Latitude": 53.63215,
        "Longitude": 10.0041609,
        "MainCityCode": "HAM",
        "MainCityDisplayName": "Hamburg (HAM) Germany",
        "MainCityName": "Hamburg",
        "Name": "Hamburg",
        "Priority": 142,
        "StateCode": null,
        "StateName": null,
        "TimeZone": -798214753
    },
    {
        "Aliases": null,
        "ContinentCode": "AS",
        "ContinentGroup": 4,
        "CountryCode": "TH",
        "CountryName": "Thailand",
        "DST": "",
        "DisplayName": "Suvarnabhumi, Bangkok (BKK) Thailand",
        "Iata": "BKK",
        "IataLink": false,
        "Icao": "VTBS",
        "Latitude": 13.6922979,
        "Longitude": 100.750694,
        "MainCityCode": "BKK",
        "MainCityDisplayName": "Bangkok (BKK) Thailand",
        "MainCityName": "Bangkok",
        "Name": "Suvarnabhumi",
        "Priority": 1462,
        "StateCode": null,
        "StateName": null,
        "TimeZone": -640089798
    }], "Offers": [
    {
        "AdultPrice": 2977.6,
        "AdultPriceEUR": 2977.6,
        "AdultPriceExclTax": 0.0,
        "Currency": "EUR",
        "FeeIndexes": [
            0,
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6
        ],
        "FlightIndex": 0,
        "IsPaymentIncluded": true,
        "MobileDeepLink": null,
        "PaymentMethods": [
            "American Express",
            "Diners Club",
            "MasterCard Credit",
            "MasterCard Debit",
            "Paypal",
            "Visa Credit",
            "Visa Debit"
        ],
        "Score": 2501.3,
        "SegmentFares": null,
        "SegmentKey": -1,
        "TicketClassIndex": 1,
        "TotalIsCalculated": false,
        "TotalPrice": 2977.6,
        "TotalPriceEUR": 2977.6,
        "TotalPriceExclTax": 0.0
    },
    {
        "AdultPrice": 4697.27,
        "AdultPriceEUR": 4697.27,
        "AdultPriceExclTax": 0.0,
        "Currency": "EUR",
        "FeeIndexes": [
            0,
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            7,
            8,
            5,
            6
        ],
        "FlightIndex": 1,
        "IsPaymentIncluded": true,
        "MobileDeepLink": null,
        "PaymentMethods": [
            "American Express",
            "Diners Club",
            "MasterCard Credit",
            "MasterCard Debit",
            "Paypal",
            "Sofortüberweisung",
            "Überweisung",
            "Visa Credit",
            "Visa Debit"
        ],
        "Score": 3438.64,
        "SegmentFares": null,
        "SegmentKey": -1,
        "TicketClassIndex": 1,
        "TotalIsCalculated": false,
        "TotalPrice": 4697.27,
        "TotalPriceEUR": 4697.27,
        "TotalPriceExclTax": 0.0
    }]
}
```

thanks

BR
Timo

Comment: include example input please.

Comment: Hi @oguzismail i added a part of the file (very big). Regards Timo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're looking at this:

```
jq '{Offers:[.Offers[] | {Price: .AdultPriceEUR, Currency: .Currency, Link: .Deeplink, Tickettyp: .TicketClassIndex, Flightindex: .FlightIndex }]}' file
```

It just creates a new object containing an `Offers` table with the content you want to put it it.

Comment: Hi Oliv, Thanks for your Input. That works fine. Thanks. It is possible to Combine that with .Offers |= reduce range(0;length) as $i (.; .[$i].Position = 1+$i)  in one command?

Comment: @TimoC : Please learn to write your Q so all issues are covered in the first posting. It may take a little more planning on your part, but it's really not fair to readers to get asked "oh, one more thing" ;-) ? OK, and good luck!

Comment: If you need to add the`Position` element, just cascade the filter: `jq '{Offers:[.Offers[] | {Price: .AdultPriceEUR, Currency: .Currency, Link: .Deeplink, Tickettyp: .TicketClassIndex, Flightindex: .FlightIndex }]} | (.Offers |= reduce range(0;length) as $i (.; .[$i].Position =
1+$i))' file`.

Comment: @shellter You are right. Normally i written my question after some lessons with Peak for those rules. In that Situation the second part was unclear, since i forgott that jq 1.5 have an bug under Windows that you can not address two jq modifications on the same file. I had to open a second question for that. Sorry for that. Regards Timo